# coffeescriptでのfunctionの書き方を教えてください。

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

javascriptのfunctionをCoffeeScriptの形式に書き換えたいんです。
検索では下記のような書き方が多かったです。

```
function名 = ->
 return
```

ですが、これをjavascriptにしてみると下記の通りになりますね。

```
function名 = function() { }
```

私が欲しいのは例えば下記のような形のfunctionをCoffeeScript形式に書き換えたいんです。

```
function a() {
  return 1;
}
```

上記のfunctionをCoffeeScript形式に書いていただければと思います。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CoffeeScriptについてはまずこちらを読んでみるといいと思います。英語がわからなくてもコード部分を見れば内容はつかめます。

http://coffeescript.org/

また、下のリンク先のサイトはJavaScriptのコードをCoffeeScriptに変換してくれます（逆も可能）。

http://js2.coffee/

最後に、質問のコードは次のようになります。

```
a = () ->
  1
```

Answer (score 0):

そもそもfunctionに名前が付かなければならないケースは
JavaScriptには滅多にないので書けません。
（JavaScript Ninjaの極意によれば若干動作が変わったりするようなのでこのように書いてます）

```
// CoffeeScript
class Person
  constructor: (options) ->
    {@name, @age, @height = 'average'} = options

// JavaScript
Person = (function() {
  function Person(options) {
    var ref;
    this.name = options.name, this.age = options.age, this.height = (ref = options.height) != null ? ref : 'average';
  }
  return Person;
})();
```

クラスを定義したらコンストラクタでこの書き方を使ってくれる程度のものです。

```
`function a(){
  // hogehoge
}`
```

こんな風にバッククォートで囲うと生のJavaScriptが使えるので、
どうしてもという箇所で使うくらいだと思います。